# jquery cycle divs randomly then add class and remove after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to cycle through a series of div at random. Each time it selects a div it adds a class of `.active-key` then removes it again and moves onto another div after a certain amount of time. Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

```
<div id="keyboard">
   <div class="key">
   <div class="key active key">
   <div class="key">
   <div class="key">
   <div class="key">
   <div class="key">
</div>

var divs = $('#keyboard .key ').addClass('active-key'), 
i = 0; 

(function cycle() { 

divs.eq(i).show(0) 
.delay(1000) 
.removeClass('active-key'); 

i = ++i % divs.length; 

})();
```

---

If you are working with SVG you have to use attr instead of class.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjrxb0tr/3/) for final working SVG example

Comment: So random or one by one (looking at `++i % divs.length;`)?

Comment: Randomly, not one by one, yea sorry the code above is based on something I was trying to tweak around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For random items selection you can try something like this:

```js
var divs = $('#keyboard .key');

(function cycle() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length);
        divs.removeClass('active-key')
            .eq(index).addClass('active-key');
        cycle();
    }, 1000);
    
})();
```

```css
.key {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #EEE;
    display: inline-block;
}
.key.active-key {
    background: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keyboard">
    <div class="key active-key"></div>
    <div class="key"></div>
    <div class="key"></div>
    <div class="key"></div>
    <div class="key"></div>
    <div class="key"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank that works perfectly in your example, but its not actually on a div its on paths (I thought using divs would be easier to understand) I have made a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rjrxb0tr/ where its not cycling through the divs.

Comment: Not to worry I figured out you have to use attr instead of class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, jQuery can't add/removeClass to SVG elements. Attr will work: `divs.attr('class', 'key').eq(index).attr('class', 'key active-key');`

Answer (score 0):

Working from your code, I made this:

CSS

```
.key {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="keyboard">
   <div class="key"></div>
   <div class="key active"></div>
   <div class="key"></div>
   <div class="key"></div>
   <div class="key"></div>
   <div class="key"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var loop = window.setInterval(function() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*5) + 1; // 5 is the length of divs
    var i = 0;
    $('.key').removeClass('active');
    $('.key').each(function() {
        if(rand == i) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        i++;
    });

    // Stop the loop with `enter code here`
    //  clearInterval(loop);

}, 500);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function f1()
 {
    var childSize=$("#keyboard").children().size();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#keyboard div").removeClass("active-key");
        var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*(childSize));

      $("#keyboard").find("div:nth-child("+(rand1+1)+")").addClass("active-key");

      f1();
    },1000);
  }
});
```

You can add a extra condition of checking if a div already has the class using .hasClass() method too!